# How to invoke api from play framework

Tags: java, json, post, get, playframework-2.5

I have a JSON data that needs to be sent for an API and get JSON Response in Play framework 2.5.x .

```
JsonNode json = Json.newObject()
                    .put("ClientId", "CLIENT ID")
                    .put("UserName", "USER_NAME")
                    .put("Password", "PASSWORD")
                    .put("EndUserIp", "XXX.XXX.XX.XX");

            String url = "http://api.tektravels.com/SharedServices/SharedData.svc/rest/Authenticate";
```

May i know what needs to be done next?
Also please let me know how to send GET and POST request?
And how to handle the response.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Play's WS (web service) Client is what you are looking for. The official [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaWS) should answer all your questions.